# A subspace of the Cantor space

Tags: general-topology, descriptive-set-theory

Is The Cantor space $2^{\omega}$ homeomorphic to the subspace $2^{\omega} - \{(1,1,1,1,1,....)\}$ . If not, what it can be said about this subspace?

Comment: $2^\omega$ is compact. Is $2^\omega - \{(1,1,1,\dotsc)\}$ compact?

Comment: @DanielFischer Beat me to it.

Comment: Can't we just say that $2^w -{(1,1,...,1,..)}$ is open in the reals, as the complement of the closed set {(1,1,1,....)}. Then, by Heine-Borel, it is not compact?

Comment: @DBF: I'm not sure if I understand you but $2^{\omega}-\{(1,1,\dots)\}$ is not an open subset of reals. If you meant it is an open subset of $2^{\omega}$, then that's true, but such a set can (a priori) be closed and compact.

Answer (score 6):

$2^{\omega}-\{(1,1,\dots)\}$ is homeomorphic to $2^{\omega} \times \omega$ (i.e. product of Cantor set and natural numbers). See the spoiler for a homeomorphism.

> Map $(\underbrace{1,1,\dots,1}_{n},0,a_1,a_2,\dots)$ to $((a_1,a_2,\dots),n)$. It is easy to see that both this map and its inverse is continuous.

Comment: (And that's **really** cool, too!)

Comment: Wow, very cool.

Comment: The Cantor set minus a singleton is the unique zero-dimensional separable metric space without isolated points that is locally compact and not compact. I.e. all spaces satisfying the description are homeomorphic.

Answer (score 3):

No, because the Cantor space is compact while $2^\omega\setminus \{(1,1,1,\ldots)\}$ is not, as the sequence $(1,0,0,\ldots),(1,1,0,\ldots,),\ldots$ converges to $(1,1,1,\ldots)$ in $2^\omega$.